# Button in pop-up onclick close window and navigate to URL

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

Inside a pop-up I want to place a button, that links to another page.
Currently I use this code:

```
<button onClick="window.open('http://www.website.com');"></button>
```

But that does open a new window inside my browser.
I want onclick to close the popup and navigate to the URL in the current window.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 window.open('http://www.website.com','_top');
```

Comment: No, it does not close the popup, it navigate inside the popup to the website.